# How do I unlock a locked axis

Tags: modeling

-New to Blender, this seems like an easy fix I just don't know where to go.

-I hit something to lock the z axis and now I cannot extrude properly.

-I select faces, go to front view, when I try to extrude a guide line pops up and puts my extrusion on an unintended angle. I don't think it's normals... it seems to be some sort of guide lock along an arbitrary axis that I accidentally set?

-all work has come to a halt so any help with this would be great.

Images show my situation.

[image]

Comment: I suppose your 3D view is in local coordinates and the object is rotated around X. But hard to see as the screen captures are low res.

Comment: Hi `E` to extrude then immediately right-click to cancel. Then move it down along the Z axis with `G`+ `Z`

Comment: Thanks @lemon - I'll look into the coordinates. Sorry about the low res- this is what the file limit would allow :(

Comment: @lemon- My coordinates were messed up and i fixed it! thank you!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you, this worked as well, but it looks like my origin was messed up too. Thanks for your time!

Comment: In Object mode, Ctrl A, apply rot and scale!